# Add space between horizontal line and text inside a table - LaTeX

Tags: tables, formatting

I am creating a table in a LaTeX document. To make the table fit some restricted space, I had to split longer texts in two lines inside their cell, using package pbox. Now, the text is touching the horizontal line I include above the first row of the table. How can I increase the distance this line and the text, so they don't touch anymore?

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{lllll}
        
        \hline
        \pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Collect}} & \pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Month}} & \pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Temp}\\\textbf{(°C)}} & \pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Pluviosity}\\\textbf{(mm)}} & \pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Specimens}\\\textbf{(Nº)}} \\
        \hline
        1                & July           & 12.4               & 68                       & 6                       \\
        2                & July           & 14.1               & 85                       & 4                       \\
        3                & August         & 10.2               & 54                       & 9                       \\
        4                & August         & 12.2               & 72                       & 6                       \\
        5                & September      & 14.7               & 82                       & 14                      \\
        6                & September      & 15.4               & 65                       & 9                       \\
        \hline                  
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - Is it advisalbe to mix the capabilities of the `tabular*` and `tabularx` environments?

Comment: There's really no point in using a `tabular*` environment unless one also specifies `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` as the first item in the second argument of the `tabular*` environment.

Comment: @Mico I meant to suggest `tabularx` instead of `tabular*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually adding line breaks, you could use columns of fixed with, e.g. `p{2cm}` or use the `tabularx` package to automatically add line breaks:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[hmargin=5.5cm]{geometry}% <- just to make the page small enough to force line breaks

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llXXX}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Collect} & \textbf{Month} & \textbf{Temp} \textbf{(°C)} & \textbf{Pluviosity} \textbf{(mm)} & \textbf{Specimens} \textbf{(Nº)} \\
        \midrule
        1                & July           & 12.4               & 68                       & 6                       \\
        2                & July           & 14.1               & 85                       & 4                       \\
        3                & August         & 10.2               & 54                       & 9                       \\
        4                & August         & 12.2               & 72                       & 6                       \\
        5                & September      & 14.7               & 82                       & 14                      \\
        6                & September      & 15.4               & 65                       & 9                       \\
        \bottomrule                  
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP's main issue is that the horizontal lines are "too close" to the header material.

Comment: @Mico Yes, and if one does not use `\pbox` there is automatically enough space that the text no longer touches the lines: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M9Ld.png (or course the spacing is better with booktabs, but that's not necessary to solve the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep using `\pbox` directives, I can think of two solutions: (a) stop using `\hline` and start using `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`, three macros provided by the [booktabs](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) package; and (b) manually insert typographic struts. The results of these approaches are illustrated in the second and third table in the following screenshot. (The first table replicates the OP's code, except that no `\footnotesize` directive is employed.

You may also want to rethink using `\pbox` directives. An alternative would be the `\makecell` macro, provided by the [makecell](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/makecell) package.

The following code employs `tabular` rather than `tabular*` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros

%% Define a few typographic struts
%% (Claudio Beccari, TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}      % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.1ex]{0pt}{0pt}}% "bottom" strut

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\hline
\pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Collect}} & 
\pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Month}} & 
\pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Temp}\\ (°C)} & 
\pbox{1.75cm}{\textbf{Pluviosity}\\ (mm)} & 
\pbox{1.85cm}{\textbf{Specimens}\\ (Nº)} \\
\hline
 1 & July      & 12.4 & 68 &  6 \\
 2 & July      & 14.1 & 85 &  4 \\
 3 & August    & 10.2 & 54 &  9 \\
 4 & August    & 12.2 & 72 &  6 \\
 5 & September & 14.7 & 82 & 14 \\
 6 & September & 15.4 & 65 &  9 \\
\hline   
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
\pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Collect}} & 
\pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Month}} & 
\pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Temp}\\\textbf{(°C)}} & 
\pbox{1.75cm}{\textbf{Pluviosity}\\\textbf{(mm)}} & 
\pbox{1.85cm}{\textbf{Specimens}\\\textbf{(Nº)}} \\
\midrule
 1 & July      & 12.4 & 68 &  6 \\
 2 & July      & 14.1 & 85 &  4 \\
 3 & August    & 10.2 & 54 &  9 \\
 4 & August    & 12.2 & 72 &  6 \\
 5 & September & 14.7 & 82 & 14 \\
 6 & September & 15.4 & 65 &  9 \\
\bottomrule   
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\hline
\pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Collect}} & 
\pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Month}} & 
\pbox{1.5cm}{\textbf{Temp\Tstrut}\\ (°C\Bstrut)} & 
\pbox{1.75cm}{\textbf{Pluviosity\Tstrut}\\ (mm\Bstrut)} & 
\pbox{1.85cm}{\textbf{Specimens\Tstrut}\\ (Nº\Bstrut)} \\
\hline
 1 & July      & 12.4 & 68 &  6\Tstrut \\
 2 & July      & 14.1 & 85 &  4 \\
 3 & August    & 10.2 & 54 &  9 \\
 4 & August    & 12.2 & 72 &  6 \\
 5 & September & 14.7 & 82 & 14 \\
 6 & September & 15.4 & 65 &  9\Bstrut \\
\hline   
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```